# htaccess mod rewrite - rewrite rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to ask for help with the following: I have for example this rule mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I want to rewrite the URL www.x.cz/word to www.x.cz/word.php

This works, but problem arise in that case, if the URL is for example www.x.cz/word/xxx (shortly after another slash is some other text string). Then there is error 500. How could i solve this problem? (I would like the server to return 404 or do the same as referring to the URL www.x.cz/word.php - as if there was not the another string).

Thank you all for your willingness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak your regex like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+) $1.php [L]
```

This will rewrite both `/word/xxx` and `/word/` to `/word.php`